# $in function of mongo db is not working in nodejs as except :(

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i want to get all the document from mongo db by the number list provided by the user but 
the problem i m facing here is this ...
when i pass the value hardcoded the $in function works fine
but when i pass the req.body.userlist then it give me an empty array although the values are same

```
    routes.post(/contect,function(req,res){ 
    var userList = req.body.userList;
    var contectList = ["3423432","23432423","32342"];
    console.log(userList);  //output ["3423432","23432423","32342"]
     User.find({
     "phoneNumber" : {
     "$in":contectList
    }
     }.then(function(data){
     console.log(data);
    })
```

any one help whats wrong here

Comment: Can you add the User model to your post ?

Comment: are you sure the data is the same regarding type ? ( number, string)

Comment: also your not closing off the find query with a )

Comment: yes the data is same i m passing the same values form POSTMAN..
@Kai

Comment: You are passing string through postman. Try to parse it `User.find({ "phoneNumber" : { "$in": JSON.parse(userList) }})`

Comment: i worked man THANK YOU so much @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: can you please explain what mistake i was making ....if  its possible ..
other wise thank you for your help :) @AnthonyWinzlet

Comment: @faizanamin You are passing through `x-www-form-urlencoded` which always takes value as string format. If you want to pass it in key value format. Go to **`raw->Text->JSON`**.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved Thanks to  [Anthony Winzlet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7510657/anthony-winzlet)

the solution was simple all i need to parse the input as Anthony winzlet said

```
 `You are passing string through postman. Try to parse it User.find({ 
 "phoneNumber" 
 : { "$in": JSON.parse(userList) }}) – Anthony Winzlet`
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be an array, so try using the spread operator.
[$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

```
{ phonenumber: { $in: [...conectList] } }
```

Comment: I see no different between  `{ phonenumber: { $in: [...conectList] } }`
 vs `{ phonenumber: { $in: ...conectList } }`

Comment: i did but the out put is same.

Comment: I'm not sure if mongoose reads it the same as you and I but try adding that closing ) before then that may solve your problem

Comment: yes i missed it while posting the question here ..
otherwise there ISN'T IT a syntax error @ColinDaniel code is working fine

Comment: yes i did but its still return the empty array
  async function dbwalakam(){
      await User.find({
           phoneNumber:{
               $in:userList
           }
       }).then(function(cvcvc){
           console.log(cvcvc);
       });
   }
   dbwalakam();
@ColinDaniel